# C++ Parsing text and writing to a csv file

Tags: c++, csv, parsing, text

**My friend sent me this and I couldn't find a way to do it. **

[image]

There are million things I've tried with AI but no hope.
I would be really appreciated if someone helped me with this.
It has to be C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <regex>

// Function to split a string based on a delimiter
std::vector<std::string> splitString(const std::string& s, char delimiter) {
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string token;
    while (std::getline(ss, token, delimiter)) {
        tokens.push_back(token);
    }
    return tokens;
}

int main() {
    // Input and output file paths
    const std::string inputFile = "file_list.csv";
    const std::string outputFile = "output.csv";

    // Open the input file
    std::ifstream inFile(inputFile);
    if (!inFile.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening file: " << inputFile << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a map to store information about each student's group and questions answered
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::pair<std::string, std::vector<int>>> studentInfo;

    // Regular expression pattern for extracting information
    std::regex pattern(R"(([a-zA-Z]+)_?(\d+)_?(\d+)?.*)");

    // Read the input file line by line
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(inFile, line)) {
        // Use regex to match the pattern
        std::smatch match;
        if (std::regex_match(line, match, pattern)) {
            // Extract matched groups
            std::string groupName = match[1];
            std::string studentID = match[2];
            std::string questionNumberStr = match[3];

            // Convert question number to integer
            int questionNumber = (questionNumberStr.empty()) ? -1 : std::stoi(questionNumberStr);

            // Update the map with the student's information
            if (!studentID.empty()) {
                if (studentInfo.find(studentID) == studentInfo.end()) {
                    // If the student is not in the map, add a new entry
                    studentInfo[studentID] = std::make_pair(groupName, std::vector<int>{questionNumber});
                } else {
                    // If the student is already in the map, update the existing entry
                    if (questionNumber != -1) {
                        studentInfo[studentID].second.push_back(questionNumber);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Close the input file
    inFile.close();

    // Open the output file for writing
    std::ofstream outFile(outputFile);
    if (!outFile.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening file: " << outputFile << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Write the header to the output file
    outFile << "StudentList,GroupName,QuestionsAnswered" << std::endl;

    // Write the student information to the output file
    for (const auto& entry : studentInfo) {
        // Sort the list of questions answered by each student
        std::vector<int> questions = entry.second.second;
        std::sort(questions.begin(), questions.end());

        // Write the student information to the output file
        outFile << entry.first << "," << entry.second.first << ",";
        for (size_t i = 0; i < questions.size(); ++i) {
            outFile << questions[i];
            if (i < questions.size() - 1) {
                outFile << ",";
            }
        }
        outFile << std::endl;
    }

    // Close the output file
    outFile.close();

    std::cout << "Output file created successfully: " << outputFile << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I couldn't find a way to detach qrub,grup,or group words from the elements of the group column.
It has to be a csv file just like the example.

A part of file_list.csv

```
d_3_2211011228.cpp
d_3_2211012211.cpp.txt
D_3_2211011054.cpp.txt
d_3_2211011096 .txt
d_question1_2111011034.txt
d_question2_2111011034.txt
d_question3_2111011034.txt
Group a_1_2211011032.cpp
Group a_2_2211011032.cpp
Group a_3_2211011032.cpp
group c_QUESTION 1_2211011024.txt
```

Comment: Don't make people click on a Google Drive link to get at your data. Make a self-contained [mre] without referring people to privacy-invading information harvesters.

Comment: I fixed it. Thank you. @paddy

Comment: Not sure if this matters, but did you notice that `file_list.csv` (the one on Google Drive) contains more that a few names with blanks in them?

Comment: yes and I don't know what can I do about them other than seeking some help? :) @tbxfreeware

Comment: Please post a more formal structure definition of the input file.  Are they all one filename per line?

Comment: The most obvious solution is to read the line, then use `std::regex` to parse it. To do this, of course, you'll have to answer @ThomasMatthews question first. Without knowing the exact definition of the structure of  the input file, it's impossible to even begin trying to answer the question.

Comment: @Athos – Looking through the data file, I see that student `2211011080` is a member of two groups: `b` and `c`. Similarly, `2211011048` belongs to `c` and `d`, while `2111011094` belongs to `a` and `c`. Is it normal for a student to belong to more than one group?  Or, are these errors that your program is supposed to flag? If the former, does that mean that the map should be keyed on a combination of `student_id` and `group_id`?

Answer (score 1):

> I couldn't find a way to detach qrub,grup,or group words from the elements of the group column.

One approach would be to break each line into three parts, using the underscore (`_`) as the delimiter.

For the demonstration here, I am using struct `Fields`, in which all the members are strings. These are the "raw" fields parsed from a single line of input.

For convenience, I supplied struct `Fields` with a stream insertion operator, using the *hidden friends* idiom.

```cpp
struct Fields
{
    std::string student_id;
    std::string group;
    std::string question;

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ost, Fields const& fields)
    {
        ost << "student_id : " << std::quoted(fields.student_id)
            << "\ngroup      : " << std::quoted(fields.group)
            << "\nquestion   : " << std::quoted(fields.question)
            << "\n\n";
        return ost;
    }
};
```

Given a line from the input file, function `parse_fields` extracts the three fields (as strings), and places them in a `Fields` struct. The struct is passed as a reference parameter.

When parsing succeeds, function `parse_fields` returns `true`. If parsing fails, an error message is output to `std::cerr`, and `parse_fields` returns `false`.

```cpp
bool parse_fields(std::string const& line, Fields& fields)
{
    std::stringstream sst{ line };
    if (!std::getline(sst, fields.group, '_'))
    {
        std::cerr
            << "`parse_fields` - Could not extract `group` from `line`: "
            << std::quoted(line)
            << "\n\n";
        return false;
    }
    if (!std::getline(sst, fields.question, '_'))
    {
        std::cerr
            << "`parse_fields` - Could not extract `question` from `line`: "
            << std::quoted(line)
            << "\n\n";
        return false;
    }
    if (!std::getline(sst, fields.student_id))  // no underscore here!
    {
        std::cerr
            << "`parse_fields` - Could not extract `student_id` from `line`: "
            << std::quoted(line)
            << "\n\n";
        return false;
    }
    if (!sst.eof() && !(sst >> std::ws).eof())
    {
        std::string s;
        std::getline(sst, s);
        std::cerr
            << fields
            << "`parse_fields` - Expecting `sst.eof()`, "
            << "i.e., end-of-line, but more remains: : "
            << std::quoted(s) 
            << "\n\n";
        return false;
    }
    fields.student_id = trim_whitespace(fields.student_id);
    if (fields.student_id.empty())
    {
        std::cerr
            << "`parse_fields` - `student_id` field is empty: "
            << std::quoted(line)
            << "\n\n";
        return false;
    }
    fields.group = trim_whitespace(fields.group);
    if (fields.group.empty())
    {
        std::cerr
            << "`parse_fields` - `group` field is empty: "
            << std::quoted(line)
            << "\n\n";
        return false;
    }
    fields.question = trim_whitespace(fields.question);
    if (fields.question.empty())
    {
        std::cerr
            << "`parse_fields` - `question` field is empty: "
            << std::quoted(line)
            << '\n';
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Once you have the fields parsed, further processing can translate each one into its final form. `group` is probably the easiest. Simply convert its final character to lower case, and discard all the rest.

Other fields require more work. For `question` number, I would probably uses a couple of member functions that are part of `std::string`. Call these with `"0123456789"` as the search-for argument:

- [`find_last_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of)
- [`find_last_not_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_not_of)

With the position of the `question` clearly identified, a call to member function [`substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) will extract it for you.

A similar technique using `find_first_of` and `find_first_not_of` will get the `student_id`.

##### I can't take all the fun

Of course, that still leaves a lot of work to be done. You must find the `student_id` and `group` in your map, and then push the `question` onto the back of the question vector, and so on.

But I had to leave some of the fun for you!

##### Demonstration program

A short demonstration program follows.

I ran it against a truncated version of the data file from Google Groups:

```
File Name
A_ 2_ 2211011100.cpp
A_1_ 2211011043.cpp
a_1_2111088001.cpp
group c_QUESTION 1_2211011024.txt
GroupA_Quesiton2_2211011034.cpp
grupc_question3_2111013335_cpp.txt
```

The program includes couple of functions from my toolbox: `to_lower_in_place` and `trim_whitespace` They are relatively straightforward, as you can see in the source code. Other than that, I added function `parse_header` to skip over the first line of the data file.

Function `main` opens the file, and reads records in a loop, stopping when end-of-file is encounterd.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

void to_lower_in_place(std::string& s) noexcept
{
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(),
        [](unsigned char c) {
            return std::tolower(c);
        }
    );
}

std::string trim_whitespace(std::string const& s)
{
    // Trim leading and trailing whitespace from string `s`.
    auto const first{ s.find_first_not_of(" \f\n\r\t\v") };
    if (first == std::string::npos)
        return {};
    auto const last{ s.find_last_not_of(" \f\n\r\t\v") };
    enum : std::string::size_type { one = 1u };
    return s.substr(first, (last - first + one));
}

struct Fields
{
    std::string student_id;
    std::string group;
    std::string question;

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ost, Fields const& fields)
    {
        ost << "student_id : " << std::quoted(fields.student_id)
            << "\ngroup      : " << std::quoted(fields.group)
            << "\nquestion   : " << std::quoted(fields.question)
            << "\n\n";
        return ost;
    }
};

bool parse_header(std::istream& ist)
{
    std::string line;
    if (!std::getline(ist, line))
    {
        std::cerr << "parse_header - `std::getline` failed unexpectedly "
            "while parsing header. \n\n";
        return false;
    }
    std::string s{ trim_whitespace(line) };
    to_lower_in_place(s);
    if (s != "file name")
    {
        std::cerr 
            << "parse_header - Could not parse header: "
            << std::quoted(line)
            << " \n\n";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool parse_fields(std::string const& line, Fields& fields)
{
    std::stringstream sst{ line };
    if (!std::getline(sst, fields.group, '_'))
    {
        std::cerr
            << "`parse_fields` - Could not extract `group` from `line`: "
            << std::quoted(line)
            << "\n\n";
        return false;
    }
    if (!std::getline(sst, fields.question, '_'))
    {
        std::cerr
            << "`parse_fields` - Could not extract `question` from `line`: "
            << std::quoted(line)
            << "\n\n";
        return false;
    }
    if (!std::getline(sst, fields.student_id))  // no underscore here!
    {
        std::cerr
            << "`parse_fields` - Could not extract `student_id` from `line`: "
            << std::quoted(line)
            << "\n\n";
        return false;
    }
    if (!sst.eof() && !(sst >> std::ws).eof())
    {
        std::string s;
        std::getline(sst, s);
        std::cerr
            << fields
            << "`parse_fields` - Expecting `sst.eof()`, "
            << "i.e., end-of-line, but more remains: : "
            << std::quoted(s) 
            << "\n\n";
        return false;
    }
    fields.student_id = trim_whitespace(fields.student_id);
    if (fields.student_id.empty())
    {
        std::cerr
            << "`parse_fields` - `student_id` field is empty: "
            << std::quoted(line)
            << "\n\n";
        return false;
    }
    fields.group = trim_whitespace(fields.group);
    if (fields.group.empty())
    {
        std::cerr
            << "`parse_fields` - `group` field is empty: "
            << std::quoted(line)
            << "\n\n";
        return false;
    }
    fields.question = trim_whitespace(fields.question);
    if (fields.question.empty())
    {
        std::cerr
            << "`parse_fields` - `question` field is empty: "
            << std::quoted(line)
            << '\n';
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    enum : int { no_errors, open_error, header_error, parsing_error };
    int exit_code = no_errors;
    const std::string inputFile = "file_list.csv";
    std::ifstream ist{ inputFile };
    if (!ist.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr
            << "ERROR: Could not open `inputFile`: "
            << std::quoted(inputFile)
            << "\n\n";
        return open_error;
    }
    if (!parse_header(ist))
    {
        std::cerr
            << "ERROR: Could not parse header (i.e., first line) of `inputFile`: "
            << std::quoted(inputFile)
            << "\n\n";
        return header_error;
    }
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(ist, line))
    {
        std::cout<< "line       : " << std::quoted(line) << '\n';
        Fields fields;
        if (parse_fields(line, fields))
            std::cout << fields;
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "Skipping invalid line. \n\n";
            exit_code = parsing_error;
        }
    }
    return exit_code;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

Here is the output:

```
line       : "A_ 2_ 2211011100.cpp"
student_id : "2211011100.cpp"
group      : "A"
question   : "2"

line       : "A_1_ 2211011043.cpp"
student_id : "2211011043.cpp"
group      : "A"
question   : "1"

line       : "a_1_2111088001.cpp"
student_id : "2111088001.cpp"
group      : "a"
question   : "1"

line       : "group c_QUESTION 1_2211011024.txt"
student_id : "2211011024.txt"
group      : "group c"
question   : "QUESTION 1"

line       : "GroupA_Quesiton2_2211011034.cpp"
student_id : "2211011034.cpp"
group      : "GroupA"
question   : "Quesiton2"

line       : "grupc_question3_2111013335_cpp.txt"
student_id : "2111013335_cpp.txt"
group      : "grupc"
question   : "question3"
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the regular expression is incorrect. Below is the program I modified.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
//#include <sstream> // removed
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <regex>
#include <algorithm> // added
#include <cctype> // added

/* removed
// Function to split a string based on a delimiter
std::vector<std::string> splitString(const std::string& s, char delimiter) {
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string token;
    while (std::getline(ss, token, delimiter)) {
        tokens.push_back(token);
    }
    return tokens;
}
*/

int main() {
    // Input and output file paths
    const std::string inputFile = "file_list.csv";
    const std::string outputFile = "output.csv";

    // Open the log file // added section
    const std::string logFileName = "skipped.csv";
    std::ofstream logFile(logFileName);
    if (!logFile.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening file: " << logFileName << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Open the input file
    std::ifstream inFile(inputFile);
    if (!inFile.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening file: " << inputFile << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a map to store information about each student's group and questions answered
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::pair<std::string, std::vector<int>>> studentInfo;

    // Regular expression pattern for extracting information
    //std::regex pattern(R"(([a-zA-Z]+)_?(\d+)_?(\d+)?.*)");
    std::regex pattern(R"(([a-zA-Z]+)_[^\d_]*(\d+)_(\d+)[^\d.]*\.)"); // fixed

    // Read the input file line by line
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(inFile, line)) {
        // Use regex to match the pattern
        std::smatch match;
        //if (std::regex_match(line, match, pattern)) {
        if (std::regex_search(line, match, pattern)) { // fixed
            // Extract matched groups
            std::string groupName = match[1];
            //std::string studentID = match[2];
            std::string studentID = match[3]; // fixed
            //std::string questionNumberStr = match[3];
            std::string questionNumberStr = match[2]; // fixed

            // Convert groupName to lower case // added
            std::transform(groupName.cbegin(), groupName.cend(), groupName.begin(), [](unsigned char c) { return std::tolower(c); });

            // Convert question number to integer
            // int questionNumber = (questionNumberStr.empty()) ? -1 : std::stoi(questionNumberStr);
            int questionNumber = std::stoi(questionNumberStr); // fixed

            // Update the map with the student's information
            //if (!studentID.empty()) { // removed
                if (studentInfo.find(studentID) == studentInfo.end()) {
                    // If the student is not in the map, add a new entry
                    studentInfo[studentID] = std::make_pair(groupName, std::vector<int>{questionNumber});
                } else {
                    // If the student is already in the map, update the existing entry
                    //if (questionNumber != -1) { // removed
                        studentInfo[studentID].second.push_back(questionNumber);
                    //} // removed
                }
            //} // removed
        } else if (!line.empty()) { // added
            logFile << line << std::endl; // log filenames that fail to parse
        }
    }

    // Close the input file
    inFile.close();

    // Open the output file for writing
    std::ofstream outFile(outputFile);
    if (!outFile.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening file: " << outputFile << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Write the header to the output file
    outFile << "StudentList,GroupName,QuestionsAnswered" << std::endl;

    // Write the student information to the output file
    //for (const auto& entry : studentInfo) {
    for (auto& entry : studentInfo) { // fixed
        // Sort the list of questions answered by each student
        //std::vector<int> questions = entry.second.second;
        std::vector<int>& questions = entry.second.second; // fixed
        std::sort(questions.begin(), questions.end());

        // Write the student information to the output file
        outFile << entry.first << "," << entry.second.first << ",";
        outFile << '"'; // added
        for (size_t i = 0; i < questions.size(); ++i) {
            outFile << questions[i];
            //if (i < questions.size() - 1) {
            if (i + 1 < questions.size()) { // better way
                outFile << ",";
            }
        }
        outFile << '"'; // added
        outFile << std::endl;
    }

    // Close the output file
    outFile.close();
    logFile.close(); // added

    std::cout << "Output file created successfully: " << outputFile << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[C++ Parsing text and writing to a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77649743/c-parsing-text-and-writing-to-a-csv-file)

This looks much more like a kind of puzzle than like a student's task. Anyway I found it curious. I will show a way to make ends meet here, and leave an example and output in `C++`. My reading is by no means a final conclusion, since the description seems not to be formal enough to lead to one (or one that I could see as formal enough, anyway).

**These is a boring long post, since I am coding along and also posting intermediate code and files. *TL;DR*: do not read. Or do it just in case. :;**

### input and output files

It seems that we have an input `csv` file that has one line per answer, 3 fields and a `'_'` as delimiter. And the expected output is a synthetic `csv` file showing a single line for each student, grouping the answers. The sorting criteria on output is *stable*, meaning that the students are listed in the order that they appear on the input.

In the original full input `csv`, provided as a link in Google Drive, there was even a header *`File Name`* but I see it as just a distraction to the reader. There are no files, no contents, and the text is just this: text. And the 3rd field starts with the essential student number, if we consider the file as a 3-field `csv` that uses underline as a delimiter, but is disguised as an 1-row funny `csv` with *file names* for files that makes no sense.

As for what an `csv` file is, [RFC4180 Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180) is the reference

#### input `csv` file as provided

```
a_1_2122011022.cpp
a_2_2111011011.txt.cpp
B_2_2111011243.cpp.txt
A_3_211011011.txt
```

and this expected output as shown

[![This shows the way to extract the data][1]][1]

This seems to be done just to confuse the student, and for testing his/her ability to parse text, anyway. It is not a list of files in a 1-fields `csv` file. It is just a simple 3-fields `csv` with an `_` delimiter.

It lists 4 answers for 3 students.

- the 1st field is the group name, but just the last letter is considered.

  - As we see in the output, case must be ignored on input, and lower case used on output, since student 2011011011 appears in the description as in group `a` for question `2` and `A` for question `3`
- 2nd filed is he question number
- 3rd field is the student number, a 10-digit field. Any other data can be ignored or should be better explained :D

#### output `csv` from the task description

Based on this description (and the notes above):

```
Student list    GroupName   QuestionsAnswered
2122011022          a              1
2111011011          a              2,3
2111011243          b              2
```

The output `csv` is also a 3-field file. Nothing is said for the delimiter, but

- for consistency an underline is the obvious choice, since it is the delimiter used on input.
- the obvious choice, a comma, is not good, since the table above already uses commas to group the answers for each student.

So in this example I will go for the `_` as delimiter

Nothing is said for the `csv` format, but it is obvious that a header line is expected, since we have one under the
*"The output file should be structure as follows:"* line, so I will write one.

### from the provided code on question

The provided code is more on the `C` side of things, than on the `C++` side. As so, and being a `csv` parser, it is strange not to see the use of `scanf` and instead see `regex` included. Regular expressions are a fantastic resource but here the expression is fixed and simple, so I believe that `regex` is much more a problem than a solution in this case.

To sort a vector of things that also matches a regular expression is, for sure, a case for an algorithm. A `for_each` would be the elementary choice for a practically one-line parser. But, looking at the task description it is clear that **the output must not be sorted**. The order of the students is mantained on the output: just the additional answers from each student are grouped on the last field. See the case of student `2111011011` on the example. And note that the order is preserved.

The code seems a bit more complicated than needed, but also it seems to be almost a solution.

#### testing the original input data with Google Sheets

This is data from the original question:

```
a_1_2122011022.cpp
a_2_2111011011.txt.cpp
B_2_2111011243.cpp.txt
A_3_211011011.txt
d_3_2211011228.cpp
d_3_2211012211.cpp.txt
D_3_2211011054.cpp.txt
d_3_2211011096 .txt
d_question1_2111011034.txt
d_question2_2111011034.txt
d_question3_2111011034.txt
Group a_1_2211011032.cpp
Group a_2_2211011032.cpp
Group a_3_2211011032.cpp
group c_QUESTION 1_2211011024.tx
```

Using `File | Import` in Sheets --- of course using `-` as delimiter --- we get

```
      a          1  2122011022.cpp
      a          2  2111011011.txt.cpp
      B          2  2111011243.cpp.txt
      A          3  2111011011.txt
      d          3  2211011228.cpp
      d          3  2211012211.cpp.txt
      D          3  2211011054.cpp.txt
      d          3  2211011096 .txt
      d  question1  2111011034.txt
      d  question2  2111011034.txt
      d  question3  2111011034.txt
Group a          1  2211011032.cpp
Group a          2  2211011032.cpp
Group a          3  2211011032.cpp
group c QUESTION 1  2211011024.txt
```

So it seems that the interpretation is correct: 3 fields, all ok. We just need to insert the field names and group the answers by student.

### `C++` and an abstraction for the problem

Since the order is to be maintained it seems that, as in the provided code, `unordered_map` is a natural choice as a *container*.
The answers for each student could be also be stored in a vector, but, since we have no requirement for testing for unique values in input, we can just use a string and append the answers for each student.

#### A first prototype

The program below gets a file name as argumen and parse it, showing the results on screen

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::ifstream;
using std::string;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    string default_file{"file_list.csv"};
    string file_name{};
    if (argc < 2)
        file_name = default_file;
    else
        file_name = argv[1];
    std::cerr << "\n\tInput File is \"" << file_name
              << "\"\n";
    ifstream inFile{file_name};
    if (!inFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "\tError: " << file_name << "\n";
        return 0;
    }
    std::cout << "\t\"" << file_name << "\" is open\n";
    string      name;
    auto        lines  = 0;
    char        f[3][80]{0};  // 3 fields, 80 chars
    const char* mask = "%79[^_]_%79[^_]_%10[^_]";
    while (not inFile.eof())
    {
        getline(inFile, name);
        if (name != "")
            std::cerr << "#" << 1+lines << ":\t" << name
                      << " (" << name.size() << ")\n";
        auto res =
            sscanf(name.c_str(), mask, &f[0], &f[1], &f[2]);
        if (res == 3)
        {
            ++lines;
            std::cout << "    Fields:" << std::left
                      << "\n\t1:  \"" << f[0] << "\""
                      << "\n\t2:  \"" << f[1] << "\""
                      << "\n\t3:  \"" << f[2] << "\"\n\n";
        }
    };  // while()
    inFile.close();
    std::cerr << "\n\t\"" << file_name
              << "\" File is closed.\n\t" << lines
              << " lines read.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

For this file

```
a_1_2122011022.cpp
a_2_2111011011.txt.cpp
B_2_2111011243.cpp.txt
A_3_2111011011.txt
```

it shows

```
#1:     a_1_2122011022.cpp (18)
    Fields:
        1:  "a"
        2:  "1"
        3:  "2122011022"

#2:     a_2_2111011011.txt.cpp (22)
    Fields:
        1:  "a"
        2:  "2"
        3:  "2111011011"

#3:     B_2_2111011243.cpp.txt (22)
    Fields:
        1:  "B"
        2:  "2"
        3:  "2111011243"

#4:     A_3_2111011011.txt (18)
    Fields:
        1:  "A"
        2:  "3"
        3:  "2111011011"


        "file_list.csv" File is closed.
        4 lines read.
```

#### creating the `csv` file

Since it seems to be ok, we can use a simple `struct` to hold the map and a function to write the `csv` file.

#### a simple struct in `Answers.h`

```
#pragma once
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>

using std::string;
using Umap =
    std::unordered_map<string, std::pair<char, string>>;

struct Answers
{
    char   delimiter;  // for the csv output file
    size_t lines;
    Umap   answers;               // the map
    Answers(string, string);      // constructor from a file
    int show();                   // display contents
    int create_csv(string);       // write csv
    int insert_if_ok(char[][80]);
};
```

#### an implementation in `Answers.cpp`

This is a simple one:

- `Answers()` gets the file names and loads the data into the map
- `show()` displays the data on screen
- `create_csv()` get a file name and unload the map to disk as a `csv` file.
- `insert_if_ok()` parses the data and upload it if ok.

```
#include "Answers.h"

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

// the format for the 3 fields in the map
using Data = std::pair<string, std::pair<char, string>>;
using std::cerr;
using std::cout;

Answers::Answers(
  string file_name = "input.csv",
  string out       = "output.csv")
  : delimiter('_'), lines(0), answers({})
{
  string default_file{"input.csv"};
  if (file_name == "") file_name = default_file;
  std::ifstream inFile{file_name};
  if (!inFile.is_open())
  {
      cerr << "\tError opening \"" << file_name << "\"\n";
      return;
  }
  string      name;
  char        f[3][80]{0};  // 3 fields, 80 chars
  const char* mask = "%79[^_]_%79[^_]_%10[^_]";
  while (not inFile.eof())
  {
      getline(inFile, name);
      if (inFile.fail()) return;
      auto res =
          sscanf(name.c_str(), mask, &f[0], &f[1], &f[2]);
      if (res == 3) insert_if_ok(f);
  };
  inFile.close();
}

int Answers::show()
{
  cout << "    " << answers.size()
       << " students on file\n";
  for (auto asw : answers)
  {
      cout << "\t" << asw.first << " " << asw.second.first
           << " " << asw.second.second << "\n";
  }
  cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

int Answers::create_csv(string file_name = "output.csv")
{
  if (answers.size() < 1)
  {
      std::cerr << "no data recorded yet. Aborting\n";
  }
  string default_file{"output.csv"};
  if (file_name == "") file_name = default_file;
  std::ofstream outFile{file_name};
  if (!outFile.is_open())
  {
      cerr << "\tError creating \"" << file_name
           << "\"\n";
      return -1;
  }
  string header{
      "\"Student "
      "list\"_\"GroupName\"_\"QuestionsAnswered\""};
  std::cerr << "    Created: \"" << file_name << "\"\n";
  std::ostream_iterator<string> oit{outFile, "\n"};
  *oit++ = header;  // csv file field names
  std::for_each(
      answers.begin(), answers.end(),
      [&](Data asw)
      {
          *oit++ = asw.first + delimiter +
                   asw.second.first + delimiter +
                   asw.second.second;
      });
  outFile.close();
  return 0;
}

int Answers::insert_if_ok(char f[][80])
{
  string student{f[2]};
  // test just size not contents
  if (student.length() != 10) return -1;

  // get group as lowercase char at the end of
  // f[0]
  size_t len = strlen(f[0]);
  if (len < 1) return 0;
  char group = f[0][len - 1];
  if ((group >= 'A') and (group <= 'Z'))
      group += 0x20;  // convert to lowercase
  else if ((group < 'a') or (group > 'z'))
      return 0;

  // get answer as last digit number in f[1]
  len = strlen(f[1]);
  if (len < 1) return 0;
  char asw = f[1][len - 1];
  if ((asw < '1') or (asw > '9')) return 0;

  // now insert into map
  auto ref = answers.find(student);
  if (ref != answers.end())
  {  // check if same group
      if (group != ref->second.first) return 0;
      ref->second.second += ",";
      ref->second.second += asw;
  }
  else
  {  // first answer for this student
      string str_asw{asw};
      answers.insert(std::make_pair(
          student, std::make_pair(group, str_asw)));
  }
  return 1;
}
```

#### `main` for a test

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Answers.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    string def_in_file{"file_list.csv"};
    string def_out_file{"output.csv"};
    string in_file_name{def_in_file};
    string out_file_name{def_out_file};
    if (argc > 2) out_file_name = argv[2];
    if (argc > 1) in_file_name = argv[1];
    std::cerr << "\n\tGenerating \"" << out_file_name
              << "\" from \"" << in_file_name
              << "\"\n";
    Answers a_test(in_file_name,out_file_name);
    a_test.show();
    a_test.create_csv(out_file_name);
    return 0;
}
```

#### output for a simple test

```
SO > cat file_list.csv
a_1_2122011022.cpp
a_2_2111011011.txt.cpp
B_2_2111011243.cpp.txt
A_3_2111011011.txt


SO > p

        Generating "output.csv" from "file_list.csv"
    3 students on file
        2122011022 a 1
        2111011011 a 2,3
        2111011243 b 2

    Created: "output.csv"

SO > cat output.csv
"Student list"_"GroupName"_"QuestionsAnswered"
2122011022_a_1
2111011011_a_2,3
2111011243_b_2

SO >

SO > cat input2.csv
a_1_2122011022.cpp
a_2_2122011022.cpp
a_2_2111011011.txt.cpp
B_2_2111011243.cpp.txt
A_3_2110110111.txt
d_3_2211011228.cpp
d_3_2211012211.cpp.txt
D_3_2211011054.cpp.txt
d_3_2211011096 .txt
d_question1_2111011034.txt
d_question2_2111011034.txt
d_question3_2111011034.txt
Group a_1_2211011032.cpp
Group a_2_2211011032.cpp
Group a_3_2211011032.cpp
group c_QUESTION 1_2211011024.txt
SO >
SO > p input2.csv output2.csv

        Generating "output2.csv" from "input2.csv"
    11 students on file
        2211011096 d 3
        2122011022 a 1,2
        2211012211 d 3
        2110110111 a 3
        2111011011 a 2
        2111011243 b 2
        2211011228 d 3
        2211011054 d 3
        2111011034 d 1,2,3
        2211011032 a 1,2,3
        2211011024 c 1

    Created: "output2.csv"

SO > cat output2.csv
"Student list"_"GroupName"_"QuestionsAnswered"
2211011096_d_3
2122011022_a_1,2
2211012211_d_3
2110110111_a_3
2111011011_a_2
2111011243_b_2
2211011228_d_3
2211011054_d_3
2111011034_d_1,2,3
2211011032_a_1,2,3
2211011024_c_1

SO >
```

### a run using the original `csv` from Drive

#### the original file

Tks @tbxfreeware for posting a link to this file. It is a minimalist `csv` with 1 field and 174 records. It seems related to file names, even has a header *"File Name"* but I believe it is just a distraction to the students. There are no files, no contents, just a text, and after the 2nd underline in each line there is the 10-digit student number. Some lines have extra words and/or extra spaces and there is no formal description of what should be there, nor of what to do in case of a perceived *error*.

Anyway, this is the file (at the moment of writing this):

```
File Name
A_ 2_ 2211011100.cpp
A_1_ 2211011043.cpp
a_1_2111088001.cpp
a_1_2111012229.txt
A_1_2111011900.txt
a_1_2111012073.txt
a_1_1211011066.txt
a_1_2122011022.cpp
a_1_2111011011.txt
A_1_2111011243.txt
a_1_2111012004.txt
A_1_2211011011.cpp.txt
a_1_2211012221.txt
A_1_2211011029.txt
a_1_2211011456.cpp
a_1_2211022046.cpp
a_1_2211011099.cpp.txt
a_1_2211042092.txt
a_1_2311012023.txt
a_2_2111015001.txt
a_2_2111022009.txt
A_2_2111022021.txt
a_2_2112211033.txt
a_2_2111011077.txt
a_2_2111011062.cpp
a_2_2111011068.txt
A_2_2111011073.txt
a_2_2111011094.txt
A_2_2211011007.cpp.txt
a_2_2211011021.txt
A_2_2211011029.txt
a_2_2211011035.cpp
a_2_2211011046.cpp
a_2_2211011072.cpp.txt
a_2_2211011082.txt
a_3_2111011009.txt
A_3_2111011021.txt
a_3_2111011033.txt
a_3_2111011055.txt
a_3_2111011062.cpp
a_3_2111011068.txt
a_3_2111011094.txt
A_3_2211011007.cpp.txt
A_3_2211011029.txt
a_3_2211011072.cpp.txt
a_3_2211011082.txt
a_q1_2111011025.txt
b _ 2_ 2211011014 (2).txt
b _ 3_ 2211011014 (1).txt
B_1_2011011022.txt
b_1_2111011024.cpp
b_1_2111011045.cpp
B_1_2211011002.txt
b_1_2211011004.txt.txt
b_1_2211011017.txt
b_1_2211011033.txt
b_1_2211011080.txt
b_1_2311011095.txt
B_2_2011011022.txt
b_2_2111011024.cpp
b_2_2111011028.txt
B_2_2111011040.cpp
B_2_2111011088.txt
B_2_2211011002.txt
B_2_2211011003.cpp
b_2_2211011004.txt.txt
b_2_2211011017.txt
b_2_2211011033.txt
B_2_2211011067_.txt
b_2_2211011073.txt
b_2_2211011074.cpp
b_2_2211011080.txt
b_2_2211011104 (2).txt
b_2_2311011095.txt
B_3_2011011022.txt
b_3_2111011024.cpp
B_3_2111011040.cpp
B_3_2111011088.txt
B_3_2211011002.txt
B_3_2211011003.cpp
b_3_2211011004.txt.txt
b_3_2211011033.txt
b_3_2211011080.txt
b_3_2211011104 (1).txt
B_Q1_2111011070.cpp
B_Q2_2111011070.txt
B_Q3_2111011070.cpp
c_1_2011011051.cpp
c_1_2111011038.txt
c_1_2111011076.cpp.txt
c_1_2211011006.txt
c_1_2211011012.cpp
C_1_2211011026.txt
c_1_2211011027.cpp
C_1_2211011041.txt
c_1_2211011070.cpp
c_1_2211011101.txt
c_2_2011011051.cpp
c_2_2111011038.txt
c_2_2111011076.cpp.cpp
c_2_2211011006.txt
c_2_2211011012.cpp
C_2_2211011026.txt
c_2_2211011027.cpp
c_2_2211011037.cpp
C_2_2211011041.txt
c_2_2211011045.cpp.txt
C_2_2211011048.cpp
C_2_2211011050.cpp.txt
C_2_2211011069.txt
c_2_2211011080.cpp
c_2_2211011101.txt
c_3_2011011051.cpp
c_3_2111011038.txt
c_3_2111011076.cpp.cpp
c_3_2211011006.txt
c_3_2211011012.cpp
c_3_2211011027.cpp
C_3_2211011041.txt
c_3_2211011070.cpp
c_3_2211011101.txt
d _1 _2111011226  (1).cpp
d _2 _2111011226  (2).cpp
d _3 _2111011226  (3).cpp
d_1_2111011453.cpp
D_1_2111011059.txt
D_1_2111011090.cpp.txt
d_1_2211011048.cpp
d_1_2211411011.cpp.txt
D_1_2211011054.cpp.txt
D_1_2211011062.cpp
d_1_2241011094.txt
d_1_2211044096.txt
d_2_2111014453.cpp
D_2_2111013359.txt
D_2_2111013390.cpp.txt
d_2_2211013308.cpp
D_2_2211331054.cpp.txt
d_2_2211331096.txt
d_3_2111011053.cpp
D_3_2122011059.txt
D_3_2111221090.cpp.txt
d_3_2211011228.cpp
d_3_2211012211.cpp.txt
D_3_2211011054.cpp.txt
d_3_2211011096 .txt
d_question1_2111011034.txt
d_question2_2111011034.txt
d_question3_2111011034.txt
Group a_1_2211011032.cpp
Group a_2_2211011032.cpp
Group a_3_2211011032.cpp
group c_QUESTION 1_2211011024.txt
group c_QUESTION 2 _2211011024.txt
GroupA_Quesiton2_2211011034.cpp
GroupA_Question1_2211011034.cpp
GroupA_Question3_2211011034.cpp
GroupB_1_2211011081.txt
GroupB_2_2211011081.txt
GroupB_3_2211011081.txt
groupB_Question2_2011011038.cpp
GroupB_Question3_2011011038.cpp.txt
GroupC_Q1_2111022004.txt
GroupC_Q2_2111022004.txt
GroupC_Q3_2111011094.txt
Groupd_Q1_2111012211.txt
Groupd_Q2_2111012211.txt
Groupd_Q3_2111011046.txt
grupc_question1_2111014405.cpp.txt
Grupc_question2_2111012005.cpp.txt
grupc_question3_2111013335_cpp.txt
qroupa_question1_2211011681.txt
qroupa_question2_2211080051.txt
qroupa_question3_2211011901.txtFile Name
A_ 2_ 2211011100.cpp
A_1_ 2211011043.cpp
a_1_2111088001.cpp
a_1_2111012229.txt
A_1_2111011900.txt
a_1_2111012073.txt
a_1_1211011066.txt
a_1_2122011022.cpp
a_1_2111011011.txt
A_1_2111011243.txt
a_1_2111012004.txt
A_1_2211011011.cpp.txt
a_1_2211012221.txt
A_1_2211011029.txt
a_1_2211011456.cpp
a_1_2211022046.cpp
a_1_2211011099.cpp.txt
a_1_2211042092.txt
a_1_2311012023.txt
a_2_2111015001.txt
a_2_2111022009.txt
A_2_2111022021.txt
a_2_2112211033.txt
a_2_2111011077.txt
a_2_2111011062.cpp
a_2_2111011068.txt
A_2_2111011073.txt
a_2_2111011094.txt
A_2_2211011007.cpp.txt
a_2_2211011021.txt
A_2_2211011029.txt
a_2_2211011035.cpp
a_2_2211011046.cpp
a_2_2211011072.cpp.txt
a_2_2211011082.txt
a_3_2111011009.txt
A_3_2111011021.txt
a_3_2111011033.txt
a_3_2111011055.txt
a_3_2111011062.cpp
a_3_2111011068.txt
a_3_2111011094.txt
A_3_2211011007.cpp.txt
A_3_2211011029.txt
a_3_2211011072.cpp.txt
a_3_2211011082.txt
a_q1_2111011025.txt
b _ 2_ 2211011014 (2).txt
b _ 3_ 2211011014 (1).txt
B_1_2011011022.txt
b_1_2111011024.cpp
b_1_2111011045.cpp
B_1_2211011002.txt
b_1_2211011004.txt.txt
b_1_2211011017.txt
b_1_2211011033.txt
b_1_2211011080.txt
b_1_2311011095.txt
B_2_2011011022.txt
b_2_2111011024.cpp
b_2_2111011028.txt
B_2_2111011040.cpp
B_2_2111011088.txt
B_2_2211011002.txt
B_2_2211011003.cpp
b_2_2211011004.txt.txt
b_2_2211011017.txt
b_2_2211011033.txt
B_2_2211011067_.txt
b_2_2211011073.txt
b_2_2211011074.cpp
b_2_2211011080.txt
b_2_2211011104 (2).txt
b_2_2311011095.txt
B_3_2011011022.txt
b_3_2111011024.cpp
B_3_2111011040.cpp
B_3_2111011088.txt
B_3_2211011002.txt
B_3_2211011003.cpp
b_3_2211011004.txt.txt
b_3_2211011033.txt
b_3_2211011080.txt
b_3_2211011104 (1).txt
B_Q1_2111011070.cpp
B_Q2_2111011070.txt
B_Q3_2111011070.cpp
c_1_2011011051.cpp
c_1_2111011038.txt
c_1_2111011076.cpp.txt
c_1_2211011006.txt
c_1_2211011012.cpp
C_1_2211011026.txt
c_1_2211011027.cpp
C_1_2211011041.txt
c_1_2211011070.cpp
c_1_2211011101.txt
c_2_2011011051.cpp
c_2_2111011038.txt
c_2_2111011076.cpp.cpp
c_2_2211011006.txt
c_2_2211011012.cpp
C_2_2211011026.txt
c_2_2211011027.cpp
c_2_2211011037.cpp
C_2_2211011041.txt
c_2_2211011045.cpp.txt
C_2_2211011048.cpp
C_2_2211011050.cpp.txt
C_2_2211011069.txt
c_2_2211011080.cpp
c_2_2211011101.txt
c_3_2011011051.cpp
c_3_2111011038.txt
c_3_2111011076.cpp.cpp
c_3_2211011006.txt
c_3_2211011012.cpp
c_3_2211011027.cpp
C_3_2211011041.txt
c_3_2211011070.cpp
c_3_2211011101.txt
d _1 _2111011226  (1).cpp
d _2 _2111011226  (2).cpp
d _3 _2111011226  (3).cpp
d_1_2111011453.cpp
D_1_2111011059.txt
D_1_2111011090.cpp.txt
d_1_2211011048.cpp
d_1_2211411011.cpp.txt
D_1_2211011054.cpp.txt
D_1_2211011062.cpp
d_1_2241011094.txt
d_1_2211044096.txt
d_2_2111014453.cpp
D_2_2111013359.txt
D_2_2111013390.cpp.txt
d_2_2211013308.cpp
D_2_2211331054.cpp.txt
d_2_2211331096.txt
d_3_2111011053.cpp
D_3_2122011059.txt
D_3_2111221090.cpp.txt
d_3_2211011228.cpp
d_3_2211012211.cpp.txt
D_3_2211011054.cpp.txt
d_3_2211011096 .txt
d_question1_2111011034.txt
d_question2_2111011034.txt
d_question3_2111011034.txt
Group a_1_2211011032.cpp
Group a_2_2211011032.cpp
Group a_3_2211011032.cpp
group c_QUESTION 1_2211011024.txt
group c_QUESTION 2 _2211011024.txt
GroupA_Quesiton2_2211011034.cpp
GroupA_Question1_2211011034.cpp
GroupA_Question3_2211011034.cpp
GroupB_1_2211011081.txt
GroupB_2_2211011081.txt
GroupB_3_2211011081.txt
groupB_Question2_2011011038.cpp
GroupB_Question3_2011011038.cpp.txt
GroupC_Q1_2111022004.txt
GroupC_Q2_2111022004.txt
GroupC_Q3_2111011094.txt
Groupd_Q1_2111012211.txt
Groupd_Q2_2111012211.txt
Groupd_Q3_2111011046.txt
grupc_question1_2111014405.cpp.txt
Grupc_question2_2111012005.cpp.txt
grupc_question3_2111013335_cpp.txt
qroupa_question1_2211011681.txt
qroupa_question2_2211080051.txt
qroupa_question3_2211011901.txt
```

#### output of the example code for this file

Some lines were deleted, since the full output and the `csv` is just a matter of running the program. And the resulting `csv` can be imported into any program. It was just imported once here to Microsoft Excel.

Note that the code above:

- accepts a given student only at 1 group.
- accepts duplicate answers for a sudent if in the same group.
- this is just a toy and does no extensive testing, and was run just a few times.

```
SO > p full-original.csv full-output.csv

        Generating "full-output.csv" from "full-original.csv"
    107 students on file
        2311011095 b 1,2
        2211011029 a 1,2,3   
         
 ... some lines deleted ...

    Created: "full-output.csv"

SO >

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB8Mb.jpg
```

Comment: _It is not a list of files. It is just a simple 3-fields csv with an _ delimiter._ This would be better if you said, "It can be treated as..." The fact is that it _is_ a list of file names. The name tells you so: `file_list.csv`. More to the point, the [complete data file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jee2ez13q9_nX205IHj2IqnF5bAeKmT0/view?usp=sharing), on Google Drive, includes a header record that has a list of the fields in the file. That header shows only one field: `File Name`.

Comment: @tbxfreeware you are right, and I rewrote these sentences. As I also said, it seems to be more of a puzzle than a task, and what matters is that the (supposed) file names contains, after the 2nd `_` , the 10-digit student number. As I see, file names are not part of any task here, they are just text. Thank you from taking the time to post a link to the (other) original file. I was (am) not able to read the name in the image. I added a run of the code using this file, at the end of the post. This is just my view of this, and I wrote it just because I found it funny.

Comment: Yeah, I'm with you on the puzzle. The best I could imagine was students uploading files to a server, so the teacher could grade them. No doubt, the students would have been told the correct format for a file name, but, you know, so what! All sorts of names were uploaded, and now the teacher is trying to sort them out. BTW, here is a link to the [full-res image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6wYQ.png) at imgur.com.

Answer (score 0):

> I couldn't find a way to detach qrub,grup,or group words from the elements of the group column.

One approach would be to break each line into three parts, using the underscore (`_`) as the delimiter.

This answer describes the program I wrote to to do just that. It reads the CSV file from the OP using two main classes, `StudentAnswers` and `FileList`.

1. `StudentAnswers` – Manages a `std::map` containing data from the input file. It also contains a function to write the map to an output file.
2. `FileList` – Contains parsing functions that read the input file.

This answer is a long one. I suggest reading a bit, and then deciding whether your interest has been sparked. Otherwise, feel free to bail out!

Source code for the complete program begins in section **StudentAnswers**.

The parsing algorithms at the heart of the program are described in section **FileList**.

##### Layout of the input file

The problem specification leaves open many details of the layout of the input file. I have filled them in, by making assumptions based on the data found in the [sample data file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jee2ez13q9_nX205IHj2IqnF5bAeKmT0/view?usp=sharing) posted to Google Drive.

1. The input file is a CSV, in which no field is quoted.
2. Each record is a single line, which contains a single field.
3. The first line is a header, and contains the field name, which is `File Name`.
4. Subsequent lines contain the data. Each line holds a file name.

File names may be broken into three parts, none of which contain the underscore character (`'_'`). The underscore character acts as a separator, appearing between the first and second parts, and also between the second and third parts.

1. `group_name` – This part may contain any number of characters. The final alphabetic character, when converted to a lower-case `char`, is the `group_name`. All other characters are discarded.
2. `question_number` – This part may contain any number of characters. The final series of digit characters, when converted to type `int`, is the `question_number`. Thus, it is the number found closest to the end of this part. All other characters are discarded.
3. `student_id` – This part may contain any number of characters. The series of digits found closest to beginning, taken as a string, is the `student_id`. All other characters are discarded.

##### Map used by the application

There are three students in the sample data file who are members of two groups. Student `2211011080` is a member of `b` and `c`. Similarly, `2211011048` belongs to `c` and `d`, while `2111011094` belongs to `a` and `c`.

Based on that, I have assumed that it is okay for a student to belong to more than one group. As a consequence of this, the map defined below will use a concatenated key containing both `group_name` and `student_id`.

These trivial type aliases are designed to improve the readability of the definitions that follow.

```cpp
using StudentID = std::string;
using GroupName = char;
using QuestionNumber = int;
```

Struct `GroupStudentKey` defines the key that will be used in the map. It places `group_name` before `student_id` so that the map will be ordered first, by group, and, then, within each group, by student. The "spaceship" operator (`<=>`) causes the compiler to create default comparison operators that enforce this ordering.

```cpp
struct GroupStudentKey
{
    GroupName group_name{};
    StudentID student_id;

    // ...

    auto operator<=> (GroupStudentKey const&) const
        = default;
};
```

Class `QuestionsAnswered` manages a vector of `QuestionNumber` objects, where each `QuestionNumber` object is an `int`. It is the element type used by the map.

Class `QuestionsAnswered` has six member functions:

- `sort` – Sort the vector of question numbers into ascending order.
- `operator()` – Return a reference to the vector.
- `operator() const` – Return a const reference to the vector.
- `operator== const` – Defaulted equality operator
- `operator<<` – Output question numbers to a stream.
- `operator>>` – Input question numbers from a stream.

We now have the types used by the map. It is keyed by `GroupStudentKey`, and has elements that are `QuestionsAnswered` objects.

```cpp
    using map_type = std::map<GroupStudentKey, QuestionsAnswered>;
```

##### StudentAnswers

Class `StudentAnswers` encapsulates a map object, and provides a minimal set of tools for managing it.

The file `StudentAnswers.h` contains its declaration, along with the map defintions given above.

```cpp
// StudentAnswers.h
#ifndef STUDENT_ANSWERS_H
#define STUDENT_ANSWERS_H

#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using StudentID = std::string;
using GroupName = char;
using QuestionNumber = int;

struct GroupStudentKey
{
    GroupName group_name{};
    StudentID student_id;

    GroupStudentKey()
        = default;

    GroupStudentKey(GroupName const group_name, StudentID const& student_id)
        : group_name{ group_name }
        , student_id{ student_id }
    {}

    GroupStudentKey(GroupName const group_name, StudentID&& student_id)
        : group_name{ group_name }
        , student_id{ std::move(student_id) }
    {}

    auto operator<=> (GroupStudentKey const&) const
        = default;
};

class QuestionsAnswered
{
public:
    using vector_type = std::vector<QuestionNumber>;
    using size_type = vector_type::size_type;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<size_type, std::size_t>);

    vector_type& operator()();
    vector_type const& operator()() const;

    bool operator== (QuestionsAnswered const&) const noexcept
        = default;

    void sort();

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (
        std::ostream& ost,
        QuestionsAnswered const& questions_answered);

    friend std::istream& operator>> (
        std::istream& ist,
        QuestionsAnswered& questions_answered);

private:
    vector_type questions_answered;
};

class StudentAnswers
{
public:
    using map_type = std::map<GroupStudentKey, QuestionsAnswered>;

    enum : int { 
        no_errors
        , open_error
        , header_error
        , skipped_record
        , stream_failed
    };

    std::string static exit_msg(int const exit_code);

    void sort();

    int read_csv(
        std::string const& file_name,
        std::string const& file_name_skipped_records = "skipped.csv");

    int write_csv(std::string const& file_name);

    map_type& operator()();
    map_type const& operator()() const;

private:
    map_type student_answers;
    bool parse_field_name(std::istream& ist, std::string_view sv);
    bool parse_header(std::istream& ist, std::ostream& log);
};

#endif  // !STUDENT_ANSWERS_H
// end file: StudentAnswers.h
```

The member functions of class `StudentAnswers` are mostly self-expanatory. One important group deals with file I/O.

- `read_csv` – Read a CSV file that was written by member function `write_csv`. Clear the map, and load the data from the file. This function includes many checks, which allow it to give detailed error messages when one of the records in the input file fails to parse.
- `write_csv`– Write a CSV file containing the fields `student_id`, `group_name`, and `questions_answered` from the map.

Two versions of `operator()`—one const, and the other non-const—return a reference to the map.

- `operator()` – Return a reference to the map.
- `operator() const` – Return a const reference to the map.

The only other member functions are these:

- `sort` – Make one pass over the map, and for each element, call `questions_answered.sort()`.
- `exit_msg` – Return a `std::string` describing the `exit_code` that is supplied as an argument. These are the exit codes returned by member functions `read_csv` and `write_csv`.
- `parse_header` – Read the first line of the CSV file.
- `parse_field_name` – Helper function for `parse_header`

```cpp
// StudentAnswers.cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

#include "StudentAnswers.h"
#include "tbx.utility.h"

//======================================================================
// QuestionsAnswered
//======================================================================
QuestionsAnswered::vector_type& QuestionsAnswered::operator()() {
    return questions_answered;
}

QuestionsAnswered::vector_type const& QuestionsAnswered::operator()() const {
    return questions_answered;
}

void QuestionsAnswered::sort() {
    std::sort(questions_answered.begin(), questions_answered.end());
}

std::ostream& operator<< (
    std::ostream& ost, 
    QuestionsAnswered const& questions_answered)
{
    if (!questions_answered().empty())
    {
        using size_type = QuestionsAnswered::size_type;
        enum : size_type { one = 1u };
        size_type const n_commas{ questions_answered().size() - one };
        for (size_type  i{}; i < n_commas; ++i)
            ost << questions_answered()[i] << ',';
        ost << questions_answered().back();
    }
    return ost;
}

std::istream& operator>> (
    std::istream& ist, 
    QuestionsAnswered& questions_answered)
{
    questions_answered().clear();
    std::string s;
    if (getline(ist, s))
    {
        std::stringstream sst{ s };
        int n;
        while (std::getline(sst, s, ','))
            if (tbx::convert_to_int(s, n))
            {
                questions_answered().push_back(n);
            }
            else
            {
                std::cerr << "QuestionsAnswered: `operator>>` could not "
                    "convert " << std::quoted(s) << " to `int`.\n"
                    "Skipping this number.\n\n";
            }
    }
    return ist;
}

//======================================================================
// StudentAnswers
//======================================================================
std::string StudentAnswers::exit_msg(int const exit_code)
{
    switch (exit_code)
    {
    case StudentAnswers::no_errors:
        return "no_errors";
    case StudentAnswers::open_error:
        return "open_error";
    case StudentAnswers::header_error:
        return "header_error";
    case StudentAnswers::skipped_record:
        return "skipped_record";
    case StudentAnswers::stream_failed:
        return "stream_failed";
    default:
        return "[invalid exit_code]";
    }
}

void StudentAnswers::sort()
{
    for (auto& [key, questions_answered] : student_answers)
        questions_answered.sort();
}

int StudentAnswers::read_csv(
    std::string const& file_name,
    std::string const& file_name_skipped_records)
{
    int exit_code = no_errors;
    std::ofstream log{ file_name_skipped_records };
    if (!log.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr
            << "StudentAnswers: Could not open log file: "
            << std::quoted(file_name_skipped_records)
            << "\nThis is the file where skipped records are logged."
            << "\n\n";
        return open_error;
    }
    std::ifstream ist{ file_name };
    if (!ist.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr
            << "StudentAnswers: Could not open input file: "
            << std::quoted(file_name)
            << "\n\n";
        return open_error;
    }
    if (!parse_header(ist, log))
    {
        std::cerr
            << "StudentAnswers: Could not parse header of input file: "
            << std::quoted(file_name)
            << "\n\n";
        return header_error;
    }

    GroupStudentKey key;
    QuestionsAnswered questions_answered;
    std::string record, s;
    std::stringstream sst;

    student_answers.clear();
    while (!std::getline(ist, record).eof())
    {
        if (ist.fail())
        {
            std::cerr << "StudentAnswers: `std::getline` failed unexpectedly mid-record.\n\n";
            exit_code = stream_failed;
            break;
        }
        sst.clear();
        sst.str(record);
        if (!std::getline(sst, key.student_id, ','))
        {
            std::cerr << "StudentAnswers: Could not parse `student_id`. Skipping record.\n\n";
            log << record << '\n';
            exit_code = skipped_record;
            continue;
        }
        enum : std::string::size_type { one = 1u };
        if (!std::getline(sst, s, ',') 
            || s.length() != one
            || !tbx::is_alpha(s.front()))
        {
            std::cerr << "StudentAnswers: Could not parse `group_name`. Skipping record.\n\n";
            log << record << '\n';
            exit_code = skipped_record;
            continue;
        }
        key.group_name = tbx::to_lower(s.front());
        sst >> questions_answered;
        if (questions_answered().empty())
        {
            std::cerr << "StudentAnswers: Could not parse `questions_answered`. Skipping record.\n\n";
            log << record << '\n';
            exit_code = skipped_record;
            continue;
        }
        if (student_answers.count(key))
        {
            std::cerr << "StudentAnswers: Duplicate `key`. Skipping record.\n\n";
            log << record << '\n';
            exit_code = skipped_record;
            continue;
        }
        student_answers[key] = questions_answered;
    }
    ist.close();
    log.close();
    return exit_code;
}

int StudentAnswers::write_csv(std::string const& file_name)
{
    int exit_code = no_errors;
    std::ofstream ost{ file_name };
    if (ost.is_open())
    {
        sort();
        char const* const header = "StudentID,GroupName,QuestionsAnswered\n";
        ost << header;
        for (auto const& [key, questions_answered] : student_answers)
        ost << key.student_id
            << ',' << key.group_name
            << ',' << questions_answered
            << '\n';
        ost.close();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr
            << "StudentAnswers: Could not open output file: "
            << std::quoted(file_name)
            << "\n\n";
        exit_code = open_error;
    }
    return exit_code;
}

bool StudentAnswers::parse_field_name(
    std::istream& ist, 
    std::string_view sv)
{
    std::string s;
    if (std::getline(ist, s, ','))
    {
        s = tbx::trim_whitespace(s);
        tbx::to_lower_in_place(s);
        return s == sv;
    }
    return false;
}

bool StudentAnswers::parse_header(std::istream& ist, std::ostream& log)
{
    std::string s;
    if (!std::getline(ist, s))
    {
        std::cerr << "StudentAnswers: `std::getline` failed unexpectedly "
            "while parsing header. \n\n";
        return false;
    }
    std::stringstream sst{ s };
    if (!parse_field_name(sst, "studentid") ||
        !parse_field_name(sst, "groupname") ||
        !parse_field_name(sst, "questionsanswered") ||
        !sst.eof())
    {
        std::cerr 
            << "StudentAnswers: Invalid header: "
            << std::quoted(s)
            << "Expected: \"StudentID,GroupName,QuestionsAnswered\"\n\n";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

StudentAnswers::map_type& StudentAnswers::operator()()
{
    return student_answers;
}

StudentAnswers::map_type const& StudentAnswers::operator()() const
{
    return student_answers;
}
// end file: StudentAnswers.cpp
```

##### FileList

Class `FileList` is a file reader.

- It has no data members.
- All member functions are static.
- Function `read_csv` accepts a `StudentAnswers` object as argument, and populates it, by parsing the input file: `file_list.csv`.
- The records in `file_list.csv` have the layout described at the start of this answer.

```cpp
// FileList.h
#ifndef FILE_LIST_H
#define FILE_LIST_H

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "StudentAnswers.h"

class FileList
{
public:
    enum : int {
        no_errors
        , open_error
        , header_error
        , skipped_record
        , stream_failed
    };
    std::string static exit_msg(int const exit_code);

    int static read_csv(
        std::string const& file_name,
        StudentAnswers& student_answers,
        std::string const& file_name_skipped_records = "skipped.csv");

private:
    enum : std::string::size_type { zero, one };

    bool static parse_header(std::istream& ist, std::ostream& log);

    bool static parse_group_name(
        std::string const& record,
        std::string::size_type& pos,
        GroupStudentKey& key);

    bool static parse_question_number(
        std::string const& record,
        std::string::size_type& pos,
        QuestionNumber& question_number);

    bool static parse_student_id(
        std::string const& record,
        std::string::size_type& pos,
        GroupStudentKey& key);
};

#endif // !FILE_LIST_H
// end file: FileList.h
```

Parsing is not difficult. It is, however, a meticulous task that is quite *fiddly*. It is easy to make *off-by-one* errors, if you are not paying attention.

Member function `read_csv` runs a loop that reads one line per iteration from the input file, and stores it in string variable `record`.

The parsing routines make one pass over variable `record`, using variable `pos` to keep track of the current position. `pos` is the subscript of the next, unparsed character in `record`. `pos` is passed as a reference parameter to each of the parsing routines, in turn. When one of them updates it, the change will be seen by the others.

The parsing routines make heavy use of the `find` functions that are part of class `std::string`. All of them return the sentinel `std::string::npos`, when a search fails.

The first pair are used to find underscores.

- `record.find('_')` – Return the subscript of the first underscore in `record`.
- `record.find('_', pos)` – Return the subscript of the "next" underscore in `record`. Begin the search at position `pos`.

The next group are used to find *digit strings*. The first two search forward from position `pos`, and are used to parse `student_id`.

- `record.find_first_of("0123456789", pos)` – Search forward, beginning at position `pos`, and return the subscript of the first digit that is encountered.
- `record.find_first_not_of("0123456789", pos)` – Search forward, beginning at position `pos`, and return the subscript of the first non-digit that is encountered.

The next two search backwards from position `pos`, and are used to parse `question_number`.

- `record.find_last_of("0123456789", pos)` – Search backwards, beginning at position `pos`, and return the subscript of the first digit that is encountered.
- `record.find_last_not_of("0123456789", pos)` – Search backwards, beginning at position `pos`, and return the subscript of the first non-digit that is encountered.

In function `parse_group_id`, the strategy is to find the first underscore, and then search backwards from there, looking for an alphabetic character. The first one that is found is converted to lower-case, and stored, as the `group_id`.

Function `parse_question_number` starts by finding the next underscore, and then searchs backwards twice, from there. The first backwards search locates the final digit in `question_number`. The second backwards search locates the non-digit character that immediately precedes the first digit of `question_number`.

After the positions of the starting and ending digits in `question_number` are nailed down, a call to `std::from_chars` converts them to an `int`.

Parsing the `student_id` is similar to parsing `question_number`, except that you search forward from the second underscore, rather than backwards. No conversion to `int` is needed. A call to `substr` extracts the `student_id` as a string.

```cpp
// FileList.cpp
#include <charconv>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "FileList.h"
#include "tbx.utility.h"

std::string FileList::exit_msg(int const exit_code)
{
    switch (exit_code)
    {
    case FileList::no_errors:
        return "no_errors";
    case FileList::open_error:
        return "open_error";
    case FileList::header_error:
        return "header_error";
    case FileList::skipped_record:
        return "skipped_record";
    case FileList::stream_failed:
        return "stream_failed";
    default:
        return "[invalid exit_code]";
    }
}

int FileList::read_csv(
    std::string const& file_name,
    StudentAnswers& student_answers,
    std::string const& file_name_skipped_records)
{
    int exit_code = no_errors;
    std::ofstream log{ file_name_skipped_records };
    if (!log.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr
            << "FileList: Could not open log file: "
            << std::quoted(file_name_skipped_records)
            << "\nThis is the file where skipped records are logged."
            << "\n\n";
        return open_error;
    }
    std::ifstream ist{ file_name };
    if (!ist.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr
            << "FileList: Could not open input file: "
            << std::quoted(file_name)
            << "\n\n";
        return open_error;
    }
    if (!parse_header(ist, log))
    {
        std::cerr
            << "FileList: Could not parse header of input file: "
            << std::quoted(file_name)
            << "\n\n";
        return header_error;
    }

    GroupStudentKey key;
    QuestionNumber question_number{};
    std::string record;
    std::string::size_type pos{};

    student_answers().clear();
    while (!std::getline(ist, record).eof())
    {
        if (ist.fail())
        {
            std::cerr << "FileList: `std::getline` failed unexpectedly mid-record.\n\n";
            exit_code = stream_failed;
            break;
        }
        pos = zero;
        if (!parse_group_name(record, pos, key))
        {
            std::cerr << "FileList: Could not parse `group_name`. Skipping record.\n\n";
            log << record << '\n';
            exit_code = skipped_record;
            continue;
        }
        if (!parse_question_number(record, pos, question_number))
        {
            std::cerr << "FileList: Could not parse `question_number`. Skipping record.\n\n";
            log << record << '\n';
            exit_code = skipped_record;
            continue;
        }
        if (!parse_student_id(record, pos, key))
        {
            std::cerr << "FileList: Could not parse `student_id`. Skipping record.\n\n";
            log << record << '\n';
            exit_code = skipped_record;
            continue;
        }
        student_answers()[key]().push_back(question_number);
    }
    ist.close();
    student_answers.sort();
    return exit_code;
}

bool FileList::parse_header(std::istream& ist, std::ostream& log)
{
    std::string s;
    if (!std::getline(ist, s))
    {
        std::cerr << "FileList: `std::getline` failed unexpectedly "
            "while parsing header. \n\n";
        return false;
    }
    s = tbx::trim_whitespace(s);
    tbx::to_lower_in_place(s);
    if (s != "file name")
    {
        std::cerr
            << "FileList: Could not parse header: "
            << std::quoted(s)
            << " \n\n";
        log << s << '\n';
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool FileList::parse_group_name(
    std::string const& record,
    std::string::size_type& pos,
    GroupStudentKey& key)
{
    pos = record.find('_');
    if (pos == std::string::npos || pos == zero)
        return false;
    auto p{ pos++ };
    do {
        if (tbx::is_alpha(record[--p]))
        {
            key.group_name = tbx::to_lower(record[p]);
            return true;
        }
    } while (p > zero);
    return false;
}

bool FileList::parse_question_number(
    std::string const& record,
    std::string::size_type& pos,
    QuestionNumber& question_number)
{
    auto const start{ pos };
    pos = record.find('_', pos);
    if (pos == std::string::npos || pos == start)
        return false;
    auto p{ pos - one };
    p = record.find_last_of("0123456789", p);
    if (p == std::string::npos || p < start)
        return false;
    auto const q{ p };  // final digit in `question_number`
    p = record.find_last_not_of("0123456789", p);
    if (p == std::string::npos || p + one < start)
        return false;
    p += one;  // first digit in question_number
    auto [ptr, ec] = std::from_chars(
        &record[p],
        &record[q + one],
        question_number);
    if (ptr == &record[p])
        return false;
    ++pos;
    return true;
}

bool FileList::parse_student_id(
    std::string const& record,
    std::string::size_type& pos,
    GroupStudentKey& key)
{
    pos = record.find_first_of("0123456789", pos);
    if (pos == std::string::npos)
        return false;
    auto const p{ pos };
    pos = record.find_first_not_of("0123456789", pos);
    if (pos == std::string::npos)
        return false;
    key.student_id = record.substr(p, pos - p);
    return true;
}
// end file: FileList.cpp
```

##### Function `main`

Given classes `StudentAnswers` and `FileList`, it is a trivial matter to code function `main`. It calls the read and write functions from those classes, and reports the `exit_code`.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "FileList.h"
#include "StudentAnswers.h"

int main()
{
    const std::string input_file_name = "file_list.csv";
    const std::string output_file_name = "output.csv";

    std::cout << "Parsing file: " 
        << std::quoted(input_file_name) 
        << '\n';
    StudentAnswers student_answers;
    int exit_code = FileList::read_csv(input_file_name, student_answers);
    if (exit_code == FileList::no_errors 
        || exit_code == FileList::skipped_record)
    {
        student_answers.write_csv(output_file_name);

        // Verify that function `read_csv` works as expected.
        StudentAnswers test;
        test.read_csv(output_file_name);
        if (test() != student_answers())
            std::cerr << "Output file cannot be read back in.\n\n";
    }

    std::cout 
        << "exit_code: " 
        << FileList::exit_msg(exit_code) 
        << "\n\n";
    return exit_code;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

##### Some functions from my toolbox

```cpp
// tbx.utility.h
#ifndef TBX_UTILITY_H
#define TBX_UTILITY_H

#include <string>

namespace tbx
{
    bool convert_to_int(std::string const& s, int& n);
    bool is_alpha(char const c) noexcept;
    char to_lower(char const c) noexcept;
    void to_lower_in_place(std::string& s) noexcept;
    std::string trim_whitespace(std::string const& s);
}
#endif // !TBX_UTILITY_H
// end file: tbx.utility.h
```

```cpp
// tbx.utility.cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

namespace tbx
{
    bool convert_to_int(std::string const& s, int& n)
    {
        std::stringstream sst{ s };
        if ((sst >> n) && !sst.eof())
            sst >> std::ws;
        return sst.eof() && !sst.fail();
    }
    bool is_alpha(char const c) noexcept
    {
        return static_cast<bool>(std::isalpha(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)));
    }
    char to_lower(char const c) noexcept
    {
        return static_cast<char>(std::tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)));
    }
    void to_lower_in_place(std::string& s) noexcept
    {
        std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(),
            [](unsigned char c) {
                return std::tolower(c);
            }
        );
    }
    std::string trim_whitespace(std::string const& s)
    {
        // Trim leading and trailing whitespace from string `s`.
        auto const first{ s.find_first_not_of(" \f\n\r\t\v") };
        if (first == std::string::npos)
            return {};
        auto const last{ s.find_last_not_of(" \f\n\r\t\v") };
        enum : std::string::size_type { one = 1u };
        return s.substr(first, (last - first + one));
    }
}
// end file: tbx.utility.cpp
```

##### Input

I ran the program twice, once against the full input file, and once against a truncated file.

The complete file, `file_list.csv` (from Google Drive), contains 174 records.

The truncated file has only a dozen records. Several students in the truncated file belong to more than one group. Several answered more than one question.

```
File Name
b_1_2211011080.txt
b_2_2211011080.txt
b_3_2211011080.txt
c_2_2211011080.cpp
C_2_2211011048.cpp
d_1_2211011048.cpp
a_2_2111011094.txt
a_3_2111011094.txt
GroupC_Q3_2111011094.txt
d _1 _2111011226  (1).cpp
d _2 _2111011226  (2).cpp
d _3 _2111011226  (3).cpp
```

##### Output

Output from this program is sent to two files:

1. `output.csv` – The contents of the map. This is the data that was parsed successfully. This file contains three fields: `StudentID`, `GroupName`, and `QuestionsAnswered`.
2. `skipped.csv` – Any records that cannot be parsed are written to this file.

In the two runs of the program, no parsing errors occurred. File `skipped.csv` was empty after both runs.

Here is the output generated from the truncated input file:

```
StudentID,GroupName,QuestionsAnswered
2111011094,a,2,3
2211011080,b,1,2,3
2111011094,c,3
2211011048,c,2
2211011080,c,2
2111011226,d,1,2,3
2211011048,d,1
```